# How to create a database user for oracle 11g on windows 8?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, installation, users

I am new to oracle database and therefore is trying to follow the office guide. ([link to the guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/admin.112/e18585/toc.htm#XEGSG110)) However, it seems that the guide is for Windows 7, so in step 2 - creating database user, it says:

> 1. Display the SQL command prompt window. For example, on Windows, click Start, then Programs (or All Programs), then Oracle Database 11g
>      Express Edition, and then Run SQL Command Line.

And in windows 8, there is not start button. I try to search the menu using keyword `oracle` but nothing with similar name is found. I tried to go to the Program Files directly but also no similar file found. So, how should I create a database user on Windows 8?

Comment: In the start menu search the word **sqlplus**.

Comment: It seems that your problem is not with Oracle but with Windows.  Where did they hide the "Start" button when Win8 went to a "tiled" desktop?  Google "where is the start button on windows 8".

Comment: Well, the problem is not I cannot make the start button reappear...... there is a physical windows key on my keyboard. The problem is that there is no "All Programs" / "Programs" on the menu opened?

Comment: Have you tried googling "where is the windows start button in windows 8"?  http://lmgtfy.com/?q=where+is+the+windows+start+button+in+Windows+8

Comment: If you have ever tried gogoling it, you will find that either you need to install something or you are pointed to the exact menu I mentioned. Look at the google result instead of creating a useless image.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 8 use shortcut to start command line option (Windows Key+R). It will open "Run" terminal. Then type keyword "cmd". It will start your command line then type "sqlplus" it will start sqlplus for interacting with your Oracle database. Use your SYS user with login credential for entering in sqlplus. After login into sqlplus, create your user using commands.